# Why does October CMS Markdown editor add an image in this odd format? ![](http://)

Tags: octobercms

When I use the markdown editor to add an image it is in this format -

```
![](http://)
```

Does anybody know why or how I can change this?

I just manually edit it to be a regular

```
<img>
```

element to make it work but it would be a problem for a client to do this.

Comment: That's common to all markdown. Even here in Stack Overflow and Github. You can read github specs here https://github.github.com/gfm/#images

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use HTML instead of the markdown syntax? Or does it not work?

Comment: Ok, yeah that makes sense. It does not work however when the page is loaded. I just get it as a string on screen. Is there something I have missed in my configuration somewhere? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Noob alert! I should just be using the Rich Editor huh?